# Is いつもの an adjective or the object in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

Context: Character A, a middle-aged man, suddenly enters the room where Riku, a child, is.

> Character A: 何してんだ？リク
>
> Riku: いつものおじさん

Then, in the next balloon (it's a manga), Riku explains what he was doing.

What is いつもの in the sentence above? Is it an adjective? If so would the translation be "oh, the usual man/the man that always comes here"? Or is it the object of the implicit sentence "(I'm doing) the usual, old man"? I would say it is an adjective, because if it was the object it would be いつもの**を**", right? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this simply means "the man who always comes here".

いつもの彼/いつものお客さん/etc is a common way to refer to *that* person you often see or talk about ("you-know-who"). [例の](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%BE%8B%E3%81%AE) is similar.

In reality, it's unusual to directly address a person with いつものおじさん, and this smells a bit like 説明セリフ to me. 説明セリフ is an jargon term that refers to unnatural lines in fiction (often long one) which only serve as a description *for the readers*. (Here are [typical 説明セリフ](http://ja.uncyclopedia.info/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB:%E6%96%AC%E3%81%AE%E3%83%81%E3%83%B3%E3%83%94%E3%83%A9.png) in a battle scene; he talks to himself to explain to the readers)